# Tweak reopen votes requirement

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

I was reading a post made a year ago concerning reopen votes being automated.

The proposed solution looks unwieldy at best. But it did make me wonder if a simpler solution could be utilised for smaller sites.

Currently we have 5 votes to close, and 5 to reopen. Is it possible, or could it be possible for smaller sites to tweak those numbers individually to address specific issues within the site that are of concern to the community?

Comment: I believe that Kilisi is interested in asymmetrical numbers of close/reopen votes which is not possible at this time. If it takes five to close, it takes five to reopen; three and three are the same - they're locked together... we don't have a way to allow five to close and only three to reopen.

Comment: Depending on *what* solution you'd accept, your question *could* be a [duplicate of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309689/282094). -- A different solution is to change the [privilege threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/282094), you still need 5 (however many) people but there would be more people who qualified to be amongst the 5. -- A third solution is to [expand the power of the Hammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254434/282094), allowing a single, expert, and trusted user to reopen. --- You can not (currently) have two different values, but there's a workaround.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? My grammar?

Comment: I doubt anyone downvotes a post on Meta for grammatical issues, it would be just quicker to edit the typos. The three downvotes are from users who probably disagree with your idea/proposal. Instead of asking if reducing the number of CV is possible, you could make this into a feature request. But I would put forward a more detailed explanation as to why smaller sites would benefit, e.g. [Would ELU like to start a trial of only need 3 votes to close/reopen a question?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13558/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA that could definitely be a possibility I guess, still suspecting my grammar though.