# Give Lesser Tag Badge holders Dupehammer privileges if they have a Gold badge in a related tag

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, privileges, tag-badges, dupehammer

#### Problem:

It's a fairly common occurrence for newer users to the SE network to post a question with very specific tags to a question, but not a more general, larger tag that is also appropriate. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690064/how-to-get-an-object-of-session-in-jsf) on Stack Overflow should be tagged Java, but isn't. If that question were a duplicate, a Java gold badge holder would not be able to close it as a duplicate. (Of course, BalusC has a gold badge in jsf as well, but that's besides the point).

#### Proposal:

I think that we should also give dupehammer privileges to users that:

- For very small tags, have a bronze tag badge in that tag
- For medium sized tags, have a silver tag badge in that tag

**AND**

- The user has a gold tag badge in a tag that is on the top three tags in the **Related Tags** list.

For example, in the question I linked above, if you had a silver badge in jsf, and a gold badge in Java (because it's the #2 Related tag), you would be able to dupehammer this question. In the case of jsf, this would give 5 additional users dupehammer privileges.

Update: both answers make a great point that this wouldn't really work on Meta sites because the tags are pretty skewed (mandatory tags etc.), this change should be for main sites only.

<sub>I didn't add this as an [answer to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240700/empowering-tag-badge-holders-part-ii-lets-look-at-silver) because it's not a power granted to **all** silver tag badge holders, you need to have two badges.</sub>

Comment: Hmmmm, but who decides which tags are related?

Comment: @Zizouz212 the related tags list in the sidebar when you're on a tag page

Comment: Hm, let me write a quick answer :)

Comment: Meta dupehammers are already probably ten times easier to swing, so there is no way this would be needed on metas. Otherwise, it seems like it might work.

Answer (score 5):

While I think more thing(s) need to be done to increase closure timeliness I don't agree with this approach.

For example here is the "related tags" of [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info)

[image]

That's a lot of tags that don't seem very "related".

I really think it's better when things are kept simple and clear. Especially when giving away dangerous things like <s>weapons</s> hammers.

> Update: both answers make a great point that this wouldn't really work on Meta sites because the tags are pretty skewed (mandatory tags etc.), this change should be for main sites only.

getting more complicated...

I'd be much more for just allowing silver taggers to use the dup hammer. And/Or gold dup hammers ability to close unclear what you're asking, too broad, and/or primarily opinion based with it.

Comment: Perhaps this privilege should not apply to meta sites, where the tags are somewhat skewed.

Comment: On the plus-side with this feature I could dupe-hammer every post first and then vote to re-open if I hammered wrong...

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental behind this idea is good, but there is a serious flaw with the suggested implementation: the decision of what counts as a related tag.

The related tag sidebar is a nice to have, showing potentially relevant tags when you are on a tag page. However, look at a couple tags:

```
     tag      |                 related tags
```

- [privileges](/questions/tagged/privileges):  [chat](/questions/tagged/chat), [meta](/questions/tagged/meta). What?

I don't see this as working, even if the community decides what tags are related. It would give people to much power in possibly unrelated tags.

Comment: See edit to my question.